# mongoose virtuals in typescript does not know type of this

Tags: typescript, mongoose, this, virtual

Using version 8.0

```
interface User {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

const UserSchema = new Schema(
    {
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String
    },
    {
        virtuals: {
            fullname: {
                get() {
                    const test = this.
                    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

When adding a type to the Schema, like `Schema<User>`, in vscode this shows as

```
this: {
    get(): void;
}
```

When removing the type in the Schema: `Schema()` no `<User>`..., `this` shows as

```
this: Document<any, any, FlatRecord<{
    firstName?: string | null | undefined;
    lastName?: string | null | undefined;
}>> & FlatRecord<{
    firstName?: string | null | undefined;
    lastName?: string | null | undefined;
}>
```

I want to create a virtual getter that makes use of the `_id` property and does some things with it.
I only have access to the `_id` property when NOT specifying the type like `Schema<Type>`, according to typescript. Why is that and am I not supposed to specify the type to the Schema? The docs say so.

Additionally, in the without types version (`Schema()`) `_id` is of type any so I cannot use any methods on it, should it not have methods?:

```
(property) Document<any, any, FlatRecord<{ firstName?: string | null | undefined; lastName?: string | null | undefined; }>>._id?: any
```

I would LOVE if someone explains me how to handle this I am lost. I also read a lot that an interface should not be extended by Document, so I assume this should all work without doing so.